# Calling a method with BufferedReader

Tags: java, class, methods, bufferedreader

So i have this method to read a file in my main class, and it works perfectly fine

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("how.txt"));
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while( line != null ){
        lines.add(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    //Choose a random one from the list
    Random r = new Random();
    String randString=lines.get(r.nextInt(lines.size()));
    System.out.println(randString);
```

Now, the problem is, i need to use this method multiple times in the main class, and i want to create a class for this method so that i don't have to copy and paste the whole method for different files that i want to read. I have attempted to create the class:

```
public class reader {

public static String readfile (String file) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file"));
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while( line != null ){
        lines.add(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    //Choose a random one from the list
    Random r = new Random();
    String randString=lines.get(r.nextInt(lines.size()));
    System.out.println(randString);

    return file;
}
```

}

But when i call the method in the main class like this:

```
String randString = reader.readfile("file.txt");
```

it gives me an error saying that the method "reafile(String)" is undefined for the type BufferedReader.

So how do I fix this? Or how do you create the method in a different class and call it in the main class?
Thanks :)

Comment: A few questions that will affect how to write this.  Are there multiple files?  Are the files long, such that you don't want to store them in memory?  Will you be using the method multiple times for the same file?

Comment: Are you using Java 7? If yes, use `Files.readAllLines()`

Comment: @fge where do I put that in?

Answer (score 0):

Both your class *and* your reader object are called `reader`. It's better to rename your class to something like `MyReader`. 
Some line is interpreted incorrectly because of this naming clash. What you want is `MyReader.readfile(file);`, and what your program sees is `BufferedReader.readfile(file);` because you somewhere have a `reader` object of type `BufferedReader`

Comment: You'll need to import the class containing that function into your main class.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your `reader` (object) is not of type `reader` (class) but of type `BufferedReader` (another class). This is what you need to clean up. I suggest you rename your classes/objects a bit. It is kind of messy as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

presumably your 'reader' object in

String randString = reader.readfile("file.txt");

is not referring to your class 'reader' instead you might have some variable declared in your code called 'reader' of type 'BufferedReader'.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file"));
```

should be

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

You're not using the input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I REALIZED YOUR ERROR!!!

Read this and think about it.

A FileReader is a connection stream for characters, that connects to your text file. You need to create a file.  A string is not going to cut it unless you prompt the user and give that to your FileReader object.

A good start would be this:

```
   import java.io.*;
    class ReadAFile { 
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("ENTER FILE NAME");
            String fileName = in.nextLine();
            try{

                File myFile = new File(fileName);
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 
                /* WE CHAINED THE FileReader to a BufferedReader;*/
                //additional operations
             }catch(exception ex){
                 ex.printStackTrace();
             }
    }
```

YOU CAN PUT ALL THIS INSIDE THE OTHER CLASS IF YOU WISH. JUST MAKE SURE You capitalize the class Name. I would name it something different though to avoid confusion. Maybe try LoadFile and make a loadFile method inside it.

Something along the lines of this

Then all you need to do is pass in a file. Once passed in you probably want to return the lines in the file? I can help with any additional questions

Comment: still gives the same error "reafile(String)" is undefined for the type BufferedReader."

Comment: if that is your error. you are not calling readfile as I put down. Check your spelling in your main method call

Comment: can you explain a bit more? I tried to copy and paste the code that you put down, but it still gives me that error.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you are trying to read a string not a file. I will put up what you need to do in a min. Hold on.

Comment: How do you call the method to use in a different class? what if i want to make the method not as a main method? I am attempting to make the file reader outside the main method.

Comment: If you want to call it from a different class you make the new class, make it public. I will give code in a bit. Sorry for the delay mate